# Ошибка в sql-запросе "invalid use of keyword"

Tags: delphi, sql

Delphi компелирует всё отлично, но при запуске вылетает ошибка

> invalid use of keyword. token..

```
Query1.SQL.Text:='select DISTINCT material from rezult2';
Query1.Open;
Table1.Open;

  while (Query1.fieldbyname('material').AsString<>'') do begin
  Query2.SQL.Text:='select sum(counte) from rezult2 where='+#39+Query1.fieldbyname('material').AsString+#39;
  Query2.Open;    Label1.Caption:='weg';
  Label1.Caption:=Label1.Caption+Query1.fieldbyname('material').AsString+' - '+Query2.fieldbyname('counte').AsString;
  Query2.Close;
  Query1.Next;
  end;
```

Подскажите, может можно по-другому сделать запрос. Мне надо подсчитать сумму в колонке `counte` для каждого уникального значения `material`.

Comment: у вас в запросе сразу после `where` стоит `=`. Т.е. синтакис запроса нарушен.

Answer (score 2):

а условие то где после **where**

**... where  ???тут???=...**

получается неизвестно что чему то равно

Вот так например

```
Query2.SQL.Text:='select sum(counte) from rezult2 where <какоето поле>='+#39+Query1.fieldbyname('material').AsString+#39;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select material, sum(counte) from rezult2 group by material
```